# Add Data from node.js to Google BigQuery Table

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I am working on Google BigQuery . i want to upload data to BigQuery Table from node.js . but i am facing a trouble here . when i  send my json data form  node.js app to  insert that data   in bigQuery table by using this code

```
line = {"id":"123", "dttme":"201807012130", "brwsr":"Chrome", "pg_id":"hpv1"};
const datajson=line;

const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const TableObjectHeader = {
      "tableReference": {
        "projectId": "local-bebop-277417",
        "datasetId": "local-bebop-277417:123",
        "tableId": "local-bebop-277417:123.first",
      }
    }
    const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();
const dataset = bigqueryClient.dataset(TableObjectHeader['tableReference']['datasetId']);
const table = dataset.table(TableObjectHeader['tableReference']['tableId']);
table.insert(datajson, function(err, response) {
      console.log("error:"+JSON.stringify(err));
      console.log("response:"+JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

then in console i am getting

```
error:{}
response:undefined
```

and i am not getting my datajson in BigQuery Tble ? Can any one help me how to fix this problem ?

Comment: What are your Node.js  ang node.js Bigquery client library versions?

Comment: "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^4.7.0",
    "@google-cloud/bigquery-data-transfer": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bigquery": "0.0.6",

Comment: my Node.js versi0n is v12.16.1

Comment: and i am c0nfused h0w t0 use client library ... can u pls help me f0r this ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've noticed the same error, when my GCP `projectID` was not defined during Bigquery [Node.js Client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/index.html) initialization.

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs), NodeJS developing environment has to be properly prepared, once you've decided to use `@google-cloud/bigquery` library, by setting up:

- [Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) parameters;
- [Google Cloud BigQuery API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=bigquery.googleapis.com) to be enabled;
- Target Bigquery GCP `ProjectID` explicitly via *[gcloud
  config set](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set)* for user shell session on the relevant NodeJS
  executor's machine or individually initializing for each client
  `const bigquery = new BigQuery({projectId: 'my-project'});` connection attempt to Bigquery REST API.

I've made some correctives in you initial code snippet to fix this issue:

```
line = {"id":"123", "dttme":"201807012130", "brwsr":"Chrome", "pg_id":"hpv1"};
const datajson=line;

const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const TableObjectHeader = {
      "tableReference": {
        "datasetId": "datasetId",
        "tableId": "tableId",
      }
    }
    const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery({projectId: 'my-project'});
const dataset = bigqueryClient.dataset(TableObjectHeader['tableReference']['datasetId']);
const table = dataset.table(TableObjectHeader['tableReference']['tableId']);
table.insert(datajson, function(err, response) {
      console.log("error:"+JSON.stringify(err));
      console.log("response:"+JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

Be also aware and don't share any user sensitive and confidential data across your code examples or/and explanation details to keep them only for private usage.

Comment: sir by doing this i am getting this error "errors":[{"message":"Invalid dataset ID

Comment: and another thing sir how to use query for insert like we use in Authentication set we used select query there .....

Comment: I guess the second error reflects a problem with defining `dataset ID `, thus you can make more investigation, at least now you are able to identify the cause of the error, making connection to Bigquery REST API. If you have any further question which is not related to the current topic, then it's a good habit to open a new thread.

Comment: If my involvement helped you with your current research, consider [up vote/accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer supporting the further contributors with the similar issues.

Comment: You have to specify a schema or this doesn't work - https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/issues/638